# blank purple screen on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I have installed a windows 8/ubuntu 13.04 dual boot. Grub2 seems to have been installed allright and I can boot windows 8 from it without a problem. Ubuntu booted allright the first time (right after the installer's reboot). However, whenever I try to boot it again, it just hangs at a blank purple screen. No ubuntu splash with changing dots under it. I tried ctra+slt+f1, nothing happens. I tried leaving it for a while, nothing changes. No hdd activity either.

Any idea what it might be? I read that it could be nvidia drivers (I have an nvidia 740m), but the funny thing is that it did boot and work the first time after install, and seems to have stopped after that. If it were a driver issue, shouldn't it have failed every time I reboot it? Also the first time it (successfully) booted, I seem to remember a type of nouveau DMS pointer error/printout on boot, but it booted fine after that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem - it doesn't hang, but the I get a purple screen for a while, then the Ubuntu splash and the loading dots come, and immediately goes to the login screen. This makes me think that the splash screen isn't being loaded on time. I'm not using Nvidia, however.